# Facebook API / C#: getting a friend's login status

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I've started using the [Facebook C# API](http://nuget.org/packages/Facebook) with a precise purpose: having a user ID of a friend, I need a method that outputs something like " is online / offline now".

After a rapid check, I can't see any function for this, how can I proceed? Should I move to Facebook Chat API using XMPP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll reply to myself: this seems possible using FQL queries on 'friends_online_presence'